# Finding error in reasoning about geometric series sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A *supposedly* fast method to find the sum of a geometric series is the following one.

Let
$$S = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} q^n$$
then
$$S = 1 + q\left[\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} q^n\right] = 1 + qS.$$
Hence
$$(1 - q)S = 1 \implies S = \frac1{1 - q}$$

This result, apparently correct, is actually wrong, since we have never required $|q| < 1$, and so it would seem that the geometric series converges for every value of $q$, which is not true.

I cannot find where the error lies in the derivation of the above result. Any hints?

Comment: The error is giving the "sum" a name and manipulating that name as if it were a number.

Comment: You started wrong. The expression S is only valid for |q|<1, otherwise it is inifinite (neg or pos), so your algebraic manipulation is all bogus after that.  No banana.

Comment: The error is in the second step I guess, while defining associativity of real numbers, doing $q(\sum_i a_i) = \sum_i (qa_i)$ is allowed only when the sum $\sum_i$ is finite. There is no guarantee in general that $\sum_i a_i$ was a finite real number in the first place.

Comment: @AndréNicolas but how is this different from [this calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)? There the same thing is done.

Comment: @rubik:  There is no issue about the existence of finite sums, which is what is being worked with in the linked article.

Comment: That reference clearly states the assumption that $|r|<1$ is requisite for the series to converge.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Right, I treated them as they were the same, thank you.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: *The error is giving the “sum” a name* - Yeah, I know. You gotta keep a professional distance. Making it personal is just bad for business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By multiplying $q$ by $S$ you implicitly assume that the series converges, because otherwise you would be multiplying by infinity, which doesn't work.

Comment: In response to your comment above, as I lack the reputation to reply, that is taking the sum of a finite number of terms. Taking the limit as n approaches infinity gives you a result of either infinity (if it diverges) or a value (if it converges).

Answer (score 2):

If $S = \infty$ you perform a "bad" operation:

$S = 1 + q S$ reads $\infty = 1 + q \infty$ you cannot compute $\infty - q \infty = (1-q)\infty$ since $\infty - \infty$ makes no sense